# Can't add content for My Account Tab

Tags: magento-1.7, php, customer-account

I have an issue where I can't get the content of a custom tab I made within the My Account Dashboard (Customer My Account).

Here is my config.xml:

app/code/local/Cardfever/Abonnement/etc

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Cardfever_Abonnement>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Cardfever_Abonnement>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <abonnement>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Cardfever_Abonnement</module>
                    <frontName>abonnement</frontName>
                </args>
            </abonnement>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <abonnement>
                    <file>abonnement.xml</file>
                </abonnement>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <abonnement>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Cardfever_Abonnement</module>
                    <frontName>abonnement</frontName>
                </args>
            </abonnement>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <currency>             
                <children>
                    <items module="abonnement">
                        <title>Abonnementskunder</title>
                        <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
                        <action>abonnement/adminhtml_abonnement</action>
                    </items>
                </children>
            </currency>
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <abonnement>
                            <title>Abonnement Module</title>
                            <sort_order>200</sort_order>
                        </abonnement>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>  
        </acl>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <abonnement>
                    <file>abonnement.xml</file>
                </abonnement>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>  
    <global>
        <models>
            <abonnement>
                <class>Cardfever_Abonnement_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>abonnement_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </abonnement>
            <abonnement_mysql4>
                <class>Cardfever_Abonnement_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <abonnement>
                        <table>abonnement</table>
                    </abonnement>
                </entities>
            </abonnement_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <abonnement_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Cardfever_Abonnement</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </abonnement_setup>
            <abonnement_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </abonnement_write>
            <abonnement_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </abonnement_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <abonnement>
                <class>Cardfever_Abonnement_Block</class>
            </abonnement>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <abonnement>
                <class>Cardfever_Abonnement_Helper</class>
            </abonnement>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <abonnement>
                <schedule><cron_expr>*/5 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
                <run><model>abonnement/observer::checkForPayments</model></run>
            </abonnement>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
</config>
```

Here is my frontend layout file:

/app/design/frontend/default/cardfever/layout/abonnement.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <customer_account>
        <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
            <action method="addLink">
                <name>cardfever_plus</name>
                <path>abonnement/customer/cardfeverplus</path>
                <label>Cardfever Plus</label>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account>

    <abonnement_customer_cardfeverplus> 
       <update handle="customer_account"/> 
       <reference name="content"> 
           <block type="abonnement/customer" name="cardfeverplus.abonnement" template="abonnement/customer/cardfeverplus.phtml"/>        
       </reference>
   </abonnement_customer_cardfeverplus>
</layout>
```

My IndexCrontoller which is under controllers:

app/code/local/Cardfever/Abonnement/controllers/IndexController.php

```
<?php
class Cardfever_Abonnement_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
            $this->loadLayout();
            $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Here is another controller which is also placed under controllers under the module CustomerController.php:

app/code/local/Cardfever/Abonnement/controllers/CustomerController.php

```
<?php

class Cardfever_Abonnement_CustomerController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{   
    /**
     * Checking if user is logged in or not
     * If not logged in then redirect to customer login
     */
    public function preDispatch()
    {
        parent::preDispatch();

        if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->authenticate($this)) {
            $this->setFlag('', 'no-dispatch', true);

        // adding message in customer login page
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')
                ->addSuccess(Mage::helper('abonnement')->__('Please sign in or create a new account'));
        }
    }           

    /**
     * View Your Module
     */
    public function viewAction()
    {                   
    $this->loadLayout();        
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($this->__('Your Abonnement Title'));     
    $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

My Template cardfeverplus.phtml:

app/design/frontend/default/cardfever/template/abonnement/customer/cardfeverplus.phtml

```
<div class="page-title">
    <h1><?php echo $this->__('My Tab') ?></h1>
</div>
```

My Block Customer.php:

app/code/local/Cardfever/Abonnement/Block/Customer.php

```
<?php
class Cardfever_Abonnement_Block_Customer extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    // CODE
}
```

I have feeling it has something to do with my controllers having and IndexController and CustomerController - or ? Can anybody help me out here to locate the issue to why I am not seeing the content of the tab - it goes to a 404 page atm.

Answer (score 1):

You've defined `abonnement_customer_cardfeverplus` handle in layout file. But you doesn't have `cardfeverplusAction` in your controller `Cardfever_Abonnement_CustomerController`. You've only `viewAction`.

**First solution:**
Just rename `viewAction` to `cardfeverplusAction` in `app/code/local/Cardfever/Abonnement/controllers/CustomerController.php`

**Second:**
Change layout handle `abonnement_customer_cardfeverplus` -> `abonnement_customer_view` in `/app/design/frontend/default/cardfever/layout/abonnement.xml`

**Third:**
 or load needed layout handle. Change line with `$this->loadLayout();` to `$this->loadLayout('abonnement_customer_cardfeverplus');` in `viewAction` in controller `app/code/local/Cardfever/Abonnement/controllers/CustomerController.php`.